# Finding ranges of specific character in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with python-3.x on windows 7. I have a string that consists of millions of characters. Consider for example:

```
ATCGNNNATCGATNNNNNATCGANTCG
```

I want to get the ranges that are `N`. In here, `[[4,7], [13,18], [23,24]]`.
I can not just take positions of `N`s and then convert them to ranges because it's a huge data and this method will be too slow.
It seems such an easy problem but actually no good way comes to my mind.
Is there a fast way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure how this scales to a string of millions of characters, but you could try [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> data = "ATCGNNNATCGATNNNNNATCGANTCG"
>>> spans = (g.span() for g in re.finditer('N+', data))
>>> list(spans)
[(4, 7), (13, 18), (23, 24)]
```

*Update:* Tried this with randomly generated strings of A, C, G, T, and N. For 1,000,000 characters, `list(spans)` takes less than one second, and for 10,000,000 it takes about 10 seconds on my not-at-all-new computer, finding about 1,600,000 groups of Ns.

Comment: Using `g.span()` might be marginally faster.

Comment: For millions of characters I would not consume the iterator at once with a comprehension, but other than that great approach +1

Comment: Also, no need for the parethesises around the `g.span()`

Comment: Whole 3.2 billion codes of human genome in less than five minutes!
Fantastic.
THANKS

Answer (score 2):

A solution without re:

```
from itertools import chain

def find_ranges(it, elem):
    start = None
    for i, e in enumerate(chain(it, [None])):
        if not start and e == elem:
            start = i
        elif start and e != elem:
            yield (start, i)
            start = None
```

Measuring with ipython's magic %timeit:

```
In [1]: import random
In [2]: s = [random.choice("ACGTN") for i in range(1000000)]
In [3]: %timeit list(find_ranges(s, "N"))
10 loops, best of 3: 164 ms per loop
```

**EDIT**: Added a guard to the end with chain, in order to make it work when the last item in the sequence is the searched element.

Comment: +1 for nice graphic algorithm. Just for comparison: I tested both solutions on my system, and the regex-approach is still about twice as fast. Seems my computer is really not the fastest anymore...

Comment: Thank you. Maybe the regex based solution is faster because the re module is implemented in C while mine is pure python. I beleive the same algorithm implemented in C would beat the one with regex :)